# IcCube - How to add Help on Custom widgets / Custom cell renderers?

Tags: widget, iccube-reporting

I created some Custom widget types and cell renderers using IcCube reporting V8 (ic3-reporting-api).
Is there a way to link some help to these as it exists for original components ?

Custom widget :
[image]

Custom cell renderer :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Widgets**

You can add some documentation/help that will be available in the editor via the (?) icon. The framework is searching in the server `Docs` for an MD file located either in the `ic3-reporting/app-local` folder or in the official documentation folder (i.e., `ic3-reporting/doc`).

The name of the file is built from the widget template as following:

```
"widgets." + pluginId + "." + templateType + "." + templateId
```

So, let's say you've created a custom table widget named `SimpleTable` in your plugin named `MyPluginJS` and register this widget into the `chart` section, then the MD filename would be:

```
widgets.MyPluginJS.chart.SimpleTable.md
```

This name is then translated into a path:

```
widgets/MyPluginJS/chart/SimpleTable.md
```

And it is searched first in `ic3-reporting/app-local` using first the user's locale and then English:

```
/icCube/report/ic3-reporting/app-local/doc/
    fr/widgets/MyPluginJS/chart/SimpleTable.md
    en/widgets/MyPluginJS/chart/SimpleTable.md
```

Eventually, it is searched in the `ic3-reporting/doc` folder for the English locale only:

```
/icCube/report/ic3-reporting/doc/
    en/widgets/MyPluginJS/chart/SimpleTable.md
```

But, adding your documentation to the `ic3-reporting/doc` folder is not recommended as this directory will be overwritten on each installation of a new version of the reporting application.

**Transformations**

The same mechanism is used for the transformations. The path would be as following:

```
tidyTable/transformations/MyPluginJS/SimpleRenderer.md
```

*Note that the pluginId is not used for the transformations path in v8.2.2 (this will be fixed in v8.3).*

Edit: Forgot to mention the `app-local/ic3report-config.js` must be updated as folllowing:

```
// extra. doc. localization folder
options.appDocUrlEx = "doc";
```

Comment: Just tried this and succeeded using 'ic3-reporting/doc' but then removed it as it's not the proper way. BUT using the same structure and file in 'ic3-reporting/app-local/doc', it does not work for me! Any other idea ?

Comment: Should work. Better ask the icCube support.